# Adjektive to an Adjektiv in Deutsch Deklination

Tags: adjective-ending

Is the following sentence correct:

> Angela Merkel hat hohe soziales Position

In the above sentence "*hohe*" describes the adjective "*soziales*" so it would not have an end-deklination.

e.g following would be wrong:

> Angela Merkel hat hohes soziales Position

Please tell me if I am right.

Answer (score 5):

It's singular, so you need an article or a pronoun.

> Angela Merkel hat **eine** hoh**e** sozial**e** Stellung.

(*Position* is not common for this phrase, use *Stellung* instead.)

The adjectives are *hoch* (irregular!) and *sozial*, and both *Position* and *Stellung* are feminine, it's an accusative object. That's why the adjective ending is *-e*, not *-es*. The latter is for nominative and accusative neutral adjectives with indefinite article or no article at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your root error is that *hoch* (correct declension: "hohe") does NOT actually describe the adjective *sozial* (correct declension: "soziale") here - it does describe the entire noun phrase *soziale Position*, so it has to be congruent to the noun.

- **Correct:**

> eine (hohe (soziale Position)) - *"hoch" does get declined*

The position, which is social, is high.

- **Also grammatically correct, but not what you wanted to say:**

> eine ((hoch[ ]soziale) Position) - *"hoch" does not get declined*

The position is social, and the degree of this socialness is high.

In the latter case, "hoch-" will usually get appended to "sozial", but I guess you *could* separate them if you want. The standard case for adjective modifiers is to separate them:

> eine ((ziemlich soziale) Position) - *"ziemlich" does not get declined*

Comment: Note: This is similar to English, actually. "Eine **hohe** soziale Position" = "a **high** social position" (the noun gets modified, appropriate rules of the respective language apply); "Eine **hoch**soziale Position" = "a **highly** social position" (the other adjective gets modified, appropriate rules apply again).